# Azure data lake gen2 -Validating uploaded file(MD5?)

Tags: azure, rest, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to validate the files that I upload to ADLG2 and cannot find a good way...

There is an ContentMD5 property but I don't see any why to change it or update it

even when I try to get the HEAD for the file the property is non existing
[HEAD headers response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkaBr.png)
(even that in the Storage Explorer the property exist)
[Property list in Storage Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBTju.png)

Is there any why to auto generate it on the Azure side? or some different way to validate the file?
(I don't want to upload a file then download it and compare them)

Answer (score 1):

Using REST API:

when you upload a file to azure data lake you do it in 3 steps

1. Put -> create the file in the right place in ADL
2. Patch -> action=append , you add your data to the blob
3. Patch -> action=flush , you save the blob

to validate that you added all data in stage 2 you need

add "Content-MD5" in the header with the MD5 hash encoded in base64

```
payload = "hello"
headers = {
'Content-Length': '5',
'Content-MD5': 'XUFAKrxLKna5cZ2REBfFkg==',
'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
}
```

- in case all is ok you will receive status: 202
- if the MD5 in not correct you will receive status 400 - The MD5 value specified in the request did not match with the MD5 value calculated by the server

after that you want to add the MD5 to the file(blob) property "ContentMD5"
what you need to do is to add to the header "x-ms-content-md5" the md5 base64 value so next time when you read the file you can validate the content

```
payload = {}
headers = {
'x-ms-content-md5': 'XUFAKrxLKna5cZ2REBfFkg=='
}
```